# Handling http error in react for path not found

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to handle the HTTP error in my application for the unknown path using catch and by changing the state of the application. I am changing the state of the application to display the details of the unknown path but it's not working. Can anyone suggest me how to do that? I have added my code below

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import charactersFile from "./data/characters.json"
import axios from 'axios';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {

  state = {
    movies: [],
    loading: true,
    error: ''
  };

  handleClick = character => {
    console.log(character.name);
    const PeopleUrl = `https://swapi.co/api/people/`;
    const FilmUrl = `https://swapi.co/api/films/`;

    switch (character.name) {
      case "Luke Skywalker":
        axios
          .get(`${PeopleUrl}1/`)
          .then(response =>
            Promise.all([
              axios.get(`${FilmUrl}2/`),
              axios.get(`${FilmUrl}6/`),
              axios.get(`${FilmUrl}3/`),
              axios.get(`${FilmUrl}1/`),
              axios.get(`${FilmUrl}7/`)
            ])
          )
          .then(result =>
            result.map(values =>
              this.setState({
                movies: [
                  ...this.state.movies,
                  {
                    title: values.data.title,
                    release_date: values.data.release_date
                  }
                ],
                loading: false,
                render: true
              })
            )
          );
        break;

      case "C-3PO":
        axios
          .get(`${PeopleUrl}2/`)
          .then(response =>
            Promise.all([
              axios.get(`${FilmUrl}2/`),
              axios.get(`${FilmUrl}5/`),
              axios.get(`${FilmUrl}4/`),
              axios.get(`${FilmUrl}6/`),
              axios.get(`${FilmUrl}3/`),
              axios.get(`${FilmUrl}1/`)
            ])
          )
          .then(result =>
            result.map(values =>
              this.setState({
                movies: [
                  ...this.state.movies,
                  {
                    title: values.data.title,
                    release_date: values.data.release_date
                  }
                ],
                loading: false,
                render: true
              })
            )
          );
        break;

      case "Leia Organa":
        axios.get(`${PeopleUrl}unknown/`)
          .then(response => {
            if (response.status === 404) {
              this.setState({ error: "Details not found" })
            }
          }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error); // They are other network errors
            this.setState({ error: 'Network error' })
          })
        break;

      case "R2-D2":
        axios
          .get(`${PeopleUrl}3/`)
          .then(response =>
            Promise.all([
              axios.get(`${FilmUrl}2/`),
              axios.get(`${FilmUrl}5/`),
              axios.get(`${FilmUrl}4/`),
              axios.get(`${FilmUrl}6/`),
              axios.get(`${FilmUrl}3/`),
              axios.get(`${FilmUrl}1/`),
              axios.get(`${FilmUrl}7/`)
            ])
          )
          .then(result =>
            result.map(values =>
              this.setState({
                movies: [
                  ...this.state.movies,
                  {
                    title: values.data.title,
                    release_date: values.data.release_date
                  }
                ],
                loading: false,
                render: true
              })
            )
          );
        break;

      default:
        return "No list item";
    }
  };

  render() {
    console.log(this.state);
    const Content = this.state.loading ? (
      <div style={{ marginTop: "20px", padding: "20px" }}>"Loading..."</div>
    ) : (
        <ul>
          {this.state.movies.map(movie => (
            <li key={movie.title}>
              {movie.title} - {movie.release_date}
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      );

    const List = (
      <ul>
        {charactersFile.characters.map(character => {
          return (
            <li
              key={character.name}
              onClick={() => this.handleClick(character)}
            >
              {character.name}
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
    );

    return <div className="App">{!this.state.render ? List : Content}</div>;
  }
}

export default App;
```

characters.json

```
{
  "characters": [
    {
      "name": "Luke Skywalker",
      "url": "https://swapi.co/api/people/1/"
    },
    {
      "name": "C-3PO",
      "url": "https://swapi.co/api/people/2/"
    },
    {
      "name": "Leia Organa",
      "url": "https://swapi.co/api/people/unknown/"
    },
    {
      "name": "R2-D2",
      "url": "https://swapi.co/api/people/3/"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is

1. You don't set loading to false when error occurs.
2. You don't check for errors in your render method.

First lets extract the presentation components to small function components to make the main component more simple

```
const Error = ({ message }) => <h3>{message}</h3>;

const Loader = () => (
  <div style={{ marginTop: "20px", padding: "20px" }}>"Loading..."</div>
);

const List = ({ handleClick }) => (
  <ul>
    {charactersFile.characters.map(character => {
      return (
        <li key={character.name} onClick={() => handleClick(character)}>
          {character.name}
        </li>
      );
    })}
  </ul>
);

const Content = ({ movies }) => (
  <ul>
    {movies.map(movie => (
      <li key={movie.title}>
        {movie.title} - {movie.release_date}
      </li>
    ))}
  </ul>
);
```

App

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    movies: [],
    loading: false,
    error: ""
  };

  handleClick = character => {
    // Set loading to true and error to false
    this.setState({ loading: true, error: false, movies: [] });
    console.log(character.name);

    axios
      .get(character.url)
      .then(({ data }) =>
        Promise.all(data.films.map(filmUrl => axios.get(filmUrl)))
      )
      .then(result => {
        const movies = result.map(({ data: { title, release_date } }) => ({
          title,
          release_date
        }));
        this.setState({ movies, loading: false, error: "" });
      })
      .catch(() => {
        this.setState({
          movies: [],
          loading: false,
          error: "List not found"
        });
      });
  };

  render() {
    const { error, loading, movies } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className="App">
        {/* include Content component only when there is data */}
        {movies.length > 0 ? (
          <Content movies={movies} />
        ) : (
          <List handleClick={this.handleClick} />
        )}
        {/* include Loader component when loading */}
        {loading && <Loader />}
        {/* include Error component when there is an error */}
        {error && <Error message={error} />}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

If you have any questions about the code let me know.

Working [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/k0ju3)

Comment: Thank you so much for writing so much clean code. I either want to load details or list not both at same time. How should I do that ?

Comment: I have posted my entire code and if you see I have lots of duplicate code. How should I handle that ?

Comment: @Riya You're welcome, Updated the render method of App to include List only when there is an error and not data

Comment: Could you please suggest how should I handle duplicate code ?

Comment: @Riya The api response provide you with films field you can instead of manually coding the movies, use the films field to get all the films of a character. I've updated the `handleClick ` method with `.then(({ data }) => Promise.all(data.films.map(filmUrl => axios.get(filmUrl))))`. Do it for all of your cases inside of the switch statement

Comment: @Riya I've updated the `handleClick` method to use the url from the characther parameter, now you don't need to use a switch statement and just update the characthers in your `charactersFile` with a name and a url. You can check the sandbox i updated it

Comment: You are not using urlMapper, PeopleUrl and FilmUrl ?

Comment: I think the sandbox didn't update yet, I have deleted all of them and just use the `url` from the `charactersFile`

Answer (score 0):

- 404 error was judged not by catch but by normal request.
- So you can catch 404 like `.then(res => {if(res.status === 404)}` or `.then(res => { if(!res.ok) })`

*Some example for your code*

```
axios.get(`${PeopleUrl}unknown/`)
            .then(response => {
               if(response.ok) {
                   console.log(response.data);
               } else {
                   console.log('Details not found.'); // It is 404 error
                   this.setState({ error : 'Details not found' });
               }
            })
            .catch(error => {
               console.log(error); // They are other network errors
               this.setState({ error : 'Network error' })
            })
```

Comment: Yes, I want to display a message, that details not found.

Comment: Please check my example

Comment: I want to display details not found a message on the page so that the user can see it. which I am not able to do even after implementing this.